# Tableau dashboard filtering issue (filters keep resetting)

Tags: filter, tableau-api, reset

I am fairly new to Tableau so I am not very familiar with everything. On my dashboard I have several sheet views, and when I want to drill into something specific the multiple views do change but when I press 'esc' the sheet filters reset. For example my dashboard view is filtered so it doesn't show any "Dairy" products it only shows "Meat" but when I drill into one of the views and then press 'esc' to go back it then shows me Dairy and Meat.

I am unsure on how to get around this, any advice?

Thank you